# node.js Socket hang up error while streaming an MP4 file from S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have an MP4 file sitting in an AWS S3 bucket.

The view code is like this:

```
<video width="300px" controls>
<source src="/getS3File/<full-s3-filename-here>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and the backend Node.JS code is like this:

```
exports.gets3file =  function(req, res, next) {
    var env = require("./env.js");
    var knox = require('knox');
    var s3filename = req.params.id;

    var submissionFileId = "https://TestS3File.amazonws.com/" + s3filename;  

    var s3Client = knox.createClient({
            key: aws.accessKey,
            secret: aws.secretKey,
            bucket: "testbucket"
    });

    s3Client.get(submissionFileId)
    .on('response', function(res) {    
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', res.headers['content-length']);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', res.headers['content-type']);

        if (req.fresh) {
        res.statusCode = 304;
        res.end();
        return;
        }

        if (req.method === 'HEAD') {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.end();
        return;
        }

        res.pipe(req);
    });
    res.end();
    };
```

When i execute this code, I see this error in the node log:

```
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
at CleartextStream.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1568:23)
at CleartextStream.onCryptoStreamEnd (tls.js:322:24)
at CleartextStream.g (events.js:180:16)
at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:943:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
at process._tickFromSpinner (node.js:394:15
```

Any ideas re: what I might be doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong here: You're piping to the wrong stream, you're ending your response immediately before the file starts streaming, and you're shadowing the real `res` with the `res` from the S3 request. Try something like this instead:

```
exports.gets3file =  function(req, res, next) {
  var env = require("./env.js");
  var knox = require('knox');
  var s3filename = req.params.id;

  var submissionFileId = "https://TestS3File.amazonws.com/" + s3filename;  

  var s3Client = knox.createClient({
    key: aws.accessKey,
    secret: aws.secretKey,
    bucket: "testbucket"
  });

  s3Client.get(submissionFileId)
  .on('response', function(s3res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', s3res.headers['content-length']);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', s3res.headers['content-type']);

    if (req.fresh) {
      res.statusCode = 304;
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (req.method === 'HEAD') {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    s3res.pipe(res);
  }).end();
};
```

You may want to also check `s3res.statusCode` too in case the file doesn't exist (404) for example, so that you can send the appropriate status code back to the original client.

Comment: excellent points. I fixed all the issues you pointed out, but it still does not yet work. I put in a debug stmt inside the ".on('response'" callback, and it looks like the code execution does not even go inside that function.

Comment: I've updated the code. According to the knox docs you still need to `end()` the S3 request even though it's a GET?

Comment: I found 2 more bugs in my code (thanks to your initial comment). I changed these 2 lines from:

    `res.setHeader('Content-Length', res.headers['content-length']);`
    `res.setHeader('Content-Type', res.headers['content-type']);`


to:

    `res.setHeader('Content-Length', s3Res.headers['content-length']);`
    `res.setHeader('Content-Type', s3Res.headers['content-type']);`

now the remaining issue is a runtime failure that says:

    `TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'write'`

Comment: I should add that I also included the `.end()` method you suggested.  Same error as the one I listed in the previous comment

Comment: Do you still have `res.pipe(req);` at the end of your `response` callback? It needs to be `s3res.pipe(res);`.

Comment: I did change it to:
    s3res.pipe(req)

Comment: The `req` needs to be `res`. `req` is a only a Readable stream, so you cannot write/pipe to it.

Comment: More progress thanks to the typo that you noticed. After I changed the line to read: s3Res.pipe(res)

the code now does enter the ".on('response'" callback, 
but the video still does not play anything

Comment: more info: looks like the callback is being called twice, and the when i print the headers property of the s3Res object it prints out this (the values may change, but the keys are the same):

{ 'x-amz-id-2': 'ddxQ9wiiRQnWg5RnNiH65o1AgHF3hpwjEIZsGdjyogEry/Vi8DwZYo',
 'x-amz-request-id': 'D31D3CE4FC5926F3',
  date: 'Tue, 16 Sep 2014 21:33:42 GMT',
  'last-modified': 'Thu, 11 Sep 2014 20:58:08 GMT',
  etag: '"7cd2144151e7ac80e5be7e0b207f7296"',
  'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
  'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
  'content-length': '2151603',
  server: 'AmazonS3',
  connection: 'close' }

Comment: You may have to respond with the correct/expected `Content-Type` even if S3 does not respond with what you're expecting (`video/mp4`). So change `res.setHeader('Content-Type', s3res.headers['content-type']);` to `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');`